# finding intersection of arrays to find hcf

Tags: javascript

The first function find factors of a number and works fine.

```js
//first find divisors of a number

function divisors(n) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if ((n % i) == 0) {
        result.push(i);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  //the following gives problems

function commonTerms(arr1, arr2) {
  var arr1 = [];
  arr2 = [];
  common = [];
  var m = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if ((arr1(i)) == (arr2(j))) {
        common.push(arr1(i));
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  return common;
}

var x = parseInt(prompt("number to find divisors of?"));
document.write(divisors(x));
var y = parseInt(prompt("number to find divisors of?"));
document.write("<br>" + divisors(y));
alert(commonTerms(divisors(x), divisors(y)));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>GCD</h1>

  <p>This is my first website
    <br>finding div</p>
</body>

</html>
```

It won't return anything,  the second function is the one giving me trouble. I have been looking at it for an hour. Starting to learn programming on my  own. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you redefining `var arr1 = []` inside function `commonTerms`

Comment: Thanks I guess that deletes the array input given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're accessing array items like this: `arr(i)`.
You should do it with square brackets:

```
if ((arr1[i])==(arr2[j])){
      common.push(arr1[i]);
      //...
}
```

And you don't need the round braces at all. Plus you'd better [use strict comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) (`===` instead of `==`).

So it would be:

```
if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]){
      common.push(arr1[i]);
      //...
}
```

BTW Consider checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you what a silly mistake!,  I did check that question,  although it is hard  for me to understand other people coding yet...

Answer (score 2):

First, `if ((arr1[i])==(arr2[j]))` instead of `if ((arr1(i))==(arr2(j)))`

Second, remove `var arr1=[]; arr2 =[];` as they are received parameters, and leave `var common=[]`

I would also use `m` in the loop as I guess that was your intention

Comment: It was my intention until I realized I didn't need it :S

Answer (score 1):

As I have already commented, you are resetting parameters and hence its not working. Check following code.

```js
//first find divisors of a number

function divisors(n) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if ((n % i) == 0) {
        result.push(i);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  //the following gives problems

function commonTerms(arr1, arr2) {
  common = [];
  var m = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if ((arr1(i)) == (arr2(j))) {
        common.push(arr1(i));
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  return common;
}

var x = parseInt(prompt("number to find divisors of?"));
document.write(divisors(x));
var y = parseInt(prompt("number to find divisors of?"));
document.write("<br>" + divisors(y));
alert(commonTerms(divisors(x), divisors(y)));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>GCD</h1>

  <p>This is my first website
    <br>finding div</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you I also didn't use square brackets with arrays

Comment: Yes! Saw @Alexander M. answer.